# xmodmap - remap Caps_Lock to Escape and Shift+Caps_Lock to Caps_Lock

Tags: linux, keyboard, xmodmap

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with **xmodmap**.
I want to remap `Caps_Lock` so it acts as `Escape` and `Shift+Caps_Lock` so it acts as `Caps_Lock`.
In my `~/.Xmodmap` i tried every possible combination of the following commands always with the same result:

```
clear Lock
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 =
keycode 66 = Escape Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape Caps_Lock
```

The `Caps_Lock` gets properly remapped to `Escape`

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Caps
keycode  66 = Escape Caps_Lock Escape Caps_Lock
```

**BUT** after reboot it still does lock CAPS. So it acts as both `Escape` and `Caps_Lock`.
Running **xev** i can see that the `state` switches between `0x10` and `0x12`.
While `Shift+Caps_Lock` works as expected (as `Caps_Lock`).
If i run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in my terminal after logging in i get this as before:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Caps
keycode  66 = Escape Caps_Lock Escape Caps_Lock
```

**BUT** `Caps_Lock` starts behaving as expected, only as `Escape` and does no longer lock CAPS.

I really dont get what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a way to make this work. I figured out that **X keyboard extension** yet offers an option for this.
By looking at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` i found the following line:

```
caps:escape_shifted_capslock Make unmodified Caps Lock an additional Esc, but Shift + Caps Lock behaves like regular Caps Lock
```

So i simply needed to add **caps:escape_shifted_capslock** to `XkbOptions` inside `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` this way:

```
Option "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,caps:escape_shifted_capslock"
```

After reboot `Caps_Lock` and `Shift+Caps_Lock` were behaving exactly the way i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the example from the xmodmap [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) for 'CapsLock to Control and Shift+CapsLock to CapsLock' and it worked.

```
clear lock
keycode 66 = Escape Caps_Lock NoSymbol NoSymbol
```

You might need to log out and in again.